# Handmade vactrols question concerning ROHS

Tags: led

Handmade vactrols question: If the heatshrink, [LDR](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Photoresistors_Senba-Sensing-Tech-GL5537-2_C125629.html) and LED are ROHS and made with care according to ROHS, and knowing that no other stuff is used, does that mean the vactrol is ROHS?

Comment: There is an alternative to CdS sensors, albeit perhaps not as linear and not as tame drive to conductance transfer function, and that's LED+PV+MOSFETs. You can them them integrated in one package.

Comment: *if* those are true, sure, but I've never heard of an RoHS-compliant LDR. They're always made with either cadmium sulfide or cadmium selenide, both of which contain cadmium, one of the hazardous substances that RoHS restricts.

Comment: please guys, i said i have rohs components, including the LDR is ROHS...

Comment: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Photoresistors_Senba-Sensing-Tech-GL5537-2_C125629.html

Comment: What are the part numbers of your ROHS components? Without them, your question of "can I make an ROHS item with only ROHS ingredients?" seems unlikely to be adressed,m instead attracting disagreements to your assertion that the parts are A-ok.

Comment: The data sheet says nothing about what the LDR is made of.

Answer (score 2):

LDRs generally contain cadmium and are therefore not compliant with RoHS legislation in Europe. For example, [this](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/advanced-photonix/PDV-P8103/480610) Digikey listing:

[image]

Comment: A quick look at all the LDRs available from my favourite supplier CPC showed 6 out of 6 LDRs they stock are CdS or CdSe. Ticking the 'RoHS' compliant box on digikey LDRs reduced 60 candidates to 0

Comment: i said i have rohs components, including the LDR is ROHS...

Comment: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Photoresistors_Senba-Sensing-Tech-GL5537-2_C125629.html

Comment: Sorry, but lcsc (the distributor, not manufacturer) made a mistake, they are not RoHS compliant. The company has RoHS compliant products such as photodiodes, and this is not one. Check the manufacturer website. You can find similar mistakes in all distributor parametric listings.

Answer (score 1):

Vactrols and LDRs are not going to be RoHS, due to their containing either CdS or CdSe.

You can get a RoHS, isolated, current controlled, variable resistor. [Here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/h11f3m-d.pdf) is one type, with R versus current, and application graphs reproduced below.

[image]

[image]

I had no luck searching for them as 'opto fet', but 'photo fet' returns some hits. Digikey has them under 'Optoisolators - Transistor, Photovoltaic Output' with 'output=MOSFET'.

You could also use an optoisolator with a voltage output (which are easier to find), into the gates of a pair of back to back MOSFETs (which allows you to choose your own resistance range).

Comment: i said i have rohs components, including the LDR is ROHS.

Comment: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Photoresistors_Senba-Sensing-Tech-GL5537-2_C125629.html

Comment: @matrixmodulator The data sheet doesn't claim RoHS, it's only the marketplace listing that asserts that it's RoHS compliant. The data sheet does give a spectral response curve which matches that for CdS. If you believe those are RoHS, then I have some excellent news for you. You've won $3,141,593 a lottery that you may not even remember entering. Please put your bank details, date of birth and mother's maiden name in a comment below, and I'll get the money to you immediately.

Comment: @Neil_UK - You no getty my details. But me getty a big laff. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The LDR that you link to is probably not RoHS.

The only thing that says it's RoHS is the [marketplace listing](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Photoresistors_Senba-Sensing-Tech-GL5537-2_C125629.html). How reliable are those? I don't know whether you've ever bought, for instance, LiPo batteries based on the Ah claims of a marketplace listing?

What should tell you whether it's RoHS is the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810170810_Senba-Sensing-Tech-GL5537-2_C125629.pdf). Running the chinese data sheet through Google Translate makes a good effort of most of the text, like `Dark resistance: the resistance value at the 10th second after turning off the 10Lux light`, which is what you have to do with the classic time response of CdS cells. The spectral response it gives, peaking up at 550 nm, is exactly where CdS cells peak. It does say `packaged with environmentally friendly material`, so they are aware of the issue. However, this data sheet makes no claims at all as to RoHS compliance of the components themselves.

So the fact that it looks like a CdS cell, has the spectral response and time limitations of a CdS cell, and the price of a CdS cell, all suggest to me that it's CdS, not some new RoHS-compliant material.

It depends what you want to do with your hand-made Vactrols. If you want to use a few off in a hobby project, then go ahead. The quantities of Cd involved are small, are encapsulated, and as long as you eventually dispose of it properly for electronics, no excess harm should come to you or the planet.

If you want to sell them as RoHS-compliant vactrols, then you will need to get the information directly from the original manufacturers for all the components as a Materials Safety Data Sheet, or Product Content Sheet, or Material Declaration Data Sheet, showing you the chemical analysis of the product, not just a marketplace listing.